# При установке валидатора на QLineEdit ограничивается количество вводимых символов

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qregexp

Возникла проблема, при установке валидатора в *PyQt5* количество символов ограничивается до **`1`**. 
Почему это может происходить?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 700, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
        fe = QLineEdit()
        we = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(fe,0,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(we,1,0,1,2)
        valid = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9  .,] {100}")
        val = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(valid)
        fe.setValidator(val)
#        fe.setMaxLength(4)
        we.setValidator(val)
#        we.setMaxLength(4)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, \
        QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QLineEdit


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        
#        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)                            # +++

        fe = QLineEdit()
        we = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(fe, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(we, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        
#        valid = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9  .,] {100}")
        valid = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9 .,]{15}")                         # !!! +++
        
        val = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(valid)
        fe.setValidator(val)        
        we.setValidator(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 500)
    ex.setWindowTitle('QRegExp QRegExpValidator')    
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]